# Arranging Text Via Ascending Order PHP

Tags: php

I am using this code to write to a file called posts.txt via POST:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['score'])) {
$fp = fopen("posts.txt", "r");
$size = filesize("posts.txt");
if ($size > 0) {
    $script = fread($fp, $size);
} else {
    $script = "";
}
fclose($fp);
$script = '<div style="width : 300px; position : relative"><font face="helvetica, geneva, sans serif" size="6"><b>' . $_POST['score'] . '</b></font><font face="helvetica, geneva, sans serif" size="4"><i> scored by ' . $_POST['username'] . '</i> <em> on '. $_POST['date'] . '</em></font><br><img src="Bar.png" /></div>' . $script;
$f = fopen("posts.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $script);
fclose($f);
echo "<html><head><title>Success!</title></head><body>Submission Posted!</body></html>";
}    

else {
    echo "<html><head><title>POST Request Error</title></head><body>Most set method to POST and params to be 'username' and 'score'</body></html>";
}
?>
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how I could arrange the different 'posts' in ascending order depending on `$_POST['score']`. I am completely new to php as you may be able to tell from the question so please explain it in your simplest terms. Also any code provided helps twice as much!!

Comment: It will be quite messy to read the whole file, add the new element, sort the whole lot by an sub-element, and then re-write it to the file. This is one of the situations where using a database (MySQL, SQLite, etc.) would probably be a better solution.

Comment: locally on the iphone device, or on a website?

Comment: Also, look into CSS and using stylesheets and classes - repeating the `style="x"` parameter for each element in your flatfile will make it grow in size much faster than needed.

Comment: @XcodeDev: On the webserver/website - you mentioned nothing about any iPhones in your question, and it is far easier to develop everything on the server and not focus on any one device/browser.

Comment: Also, look at http://webtint.net/tutorials/5-star-rating-system-in-php-mysql-and-jquery/ for a tutorial which, from the limited code you have provided, may be along the lines of what you are trying to create. (Google is your friend.)

Comment: What exactly is $_POST['score']? What values are within the posts.txt file? You'll need to separate each "post" in the posts.txt file with a new line or some sort of delimiter, like a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to start using mysql instead of keeping posts in a file. you can then store your records in a database, query the database for sets of results in any order you desire.

Comment: also note that if you don't have mysql, sqlite is available in most php installs, and is definitely an improvement from flat text files